# Google Bigquery SELECT count(*) on API returns 0 when Same Count(*) queryin the GBQ Console returns a count

Tags: python, google-bigquery

I'm examining the NOAA severe storms dataset in Google Bigquery and I wanted to iterate over the tables to get the storms per year between 1960 and 2022. with property damage.

```
from google.cloud import bigquery
client = bigquery.Client.from_service_account_json("secret.json")

for year in range(1960, 2023):
    query = f"""
    SELECT count(*) AS ct
    FROM `bigquery-public-data.noaa_historic_severe_storms.storms_{year}`
    WHERE damage_property > 0
    """
    query_job = client.query(query).result()
    for row in query_job:
       print(row)
```

The print statement prints results like:

```
Row((552,), {'ct': 0})
Row((620,), {'ct': 0})
Row((401,), {'ct': 0})
```

It returns 0 for the count, but excecuting the same query in the GBQ console gets me the correct result. If I use a different query:

```
    query = f"""
    SELECT *
    FROM `bigquery-public-data.noaa_historic_severe_storms.storms_{year}`
    WHERE damage_property > 0
    """
```

with the API, it works fine and gives me the correct results, the same results I get running it in the GBQ console. Why does count(*) work unexpectedly? How Do I get the correct results?

Comment: The client is working as expected, the 0 represents the the column position. The count/column value is printed as well. Try using `row.ct` to fetch the value of particular column, you can also use `row[ind]` where `ind` represents the column position.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To access your query result you'll have to use either `row[0]` or `row.ct` in the code:

```
query_job = client.query(query).result()
for row in query_job:
   print(row[0])
```

Answer (score 0):

BigQuery first returns a query object and from there you can get the result using .result().  But that is an Iterator object so you have to iterate to get the values.  In a count (*) you know that there is only one row to iterate on so you can use "next".  And that returns a row with one value in it and thus the [0].

```
   iterator = client.query(query).result()
   first_row = next(iterator)
   print(first_row[0])
```

Comment: Thank you for contributing to the Stack Overflow community. This may be a correct answer, but it’d be really useful to provide additional explanation of your code so developers can understand your reasoning. This is especially useful for new developers who aren’t as familiar with the syntax or struggling to understand the concepts. **Would you kindly [edit] your answer to include additional details for the benefit of the community?**